# The images cannot be loaded on the Expo react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm a newbie to expo / react-native

When I'm with the follwoing codes, the expo works normally.
[image]

The result:
[image]

But when I add the picture,
[image]

It's broken, and show no picture on the web-view, while with no error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the height and width into the style prop.

```
<Image 
  source={{uri:"https://picsum.photos/200"}}
  style={{height:10, width:10}}
/>
```